# Cos'è un'asse da polenta?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La chimera*, di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto:

> Controllava che non tagliassero le *albere* o che, dovendo piantarle, le piantassero; che non trasformassero i *gerbidi* (marcite) in risaie, per guadagnare più denaro; badava anche, o faceva finta di badare, alla divisione dei raccolti: annotando minuziosamente *sacchi* e *staia*, *mine* e *brente*, numero delle fascine e numero dei capponi, numero dei maiali e qualità degli stessi e così via, su un suo registro rilegato in pergamena che portava sempre stretto sotto il braccio, e che i contadini chiamavano  **“asse da polenta”,** chissà mai perché!

La mia domanda è: in cosa consiste un'asse da polenta? Per quanto ho visto su Internet, sembra si tratti di un utensile per lavorare la polenta, ma potreste spiegarmelo con più dettaglio?

Comment: Credo si tratti di questo http://www.lombardiabeniculturali.it/beni-etnoantropologici/schede/6w010-00193/ è una specie di teglia di legno che serve a servire la polenta (credo, ammetto  di non essere un esperto di questo piatto)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tratta di una forma in legno, generalmente rotonda in cui viene rovesciata la polenta appena fatta per farla raffreddare. Molto comune nel nord Italia, Lombardia e Veneto, ad esempio. È ancora  usata da chi fa la polenta in casa o in alcuni ristoranti tradizionali.

[image]

Il registro rilegato in pergamena, forse per le dimensioni e il colore, ricordava ai contadini un'asse da polenta.

Answer (score 4):

L'**asse da polenta** è una sorta di tagliere dove si rovescia la polenta direttamente dal paiolo dopo averla cucinata.

L'intento dei contadini era canzonatorio in quanto adattavano il registro rilegato in pergamena ad un oggetto comune della loro vita quotidiana, dato che la polenta era un alimento diffuso nella civiltà contadina.